# How to implement type-safe CRTP in Python?

Tags: python, mypy, crtp

I'm familiar with curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP) implementation in C++ and C# programming languages. But, how we can achieve the same idea in the Python and type-safe (using Mypy)?

This code may not be functioning properly, but symbolically, it provides an idea:

```
class GenericParent(Generic[T]):
    pass

class Derived(GenericParent[Derived]):
    pass
```

I've tried specializing the `GenericParent` type variables by the `Derived` class but the `Mypy` gives error.

Comment: CRTP is used in C++ to avoid the performance overhead of dynamic polymorphism and is only relevant in compiled languages. I see no point in trying to force the concept into Python which is neither compiled nor statically typed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a static typing pattern, CRTP should be supported out of the box across major Python type checking implementations. mypy itself should not give you errors when you declare `class Derived(GenericParent[Derived]): ...` (see the following [mypy playground demo](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=5989387428d22559bacc0ff0890a3a94)) - you might be seeing errors from another linter or the IDE you're using, because this code will fail at runtime.

You have several options to make this work. Options 1 and 2 assumes that you don't need runtime introspection; option 3 will handle runtime introspection in a limited fashion.

1. Write a [`.pyi` stub file](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs.html), which has no runtime implementation and thus won't cause any runtime errors. The CRTP pattern is used in [Python's own typeshed to statically model the builtin `str` type](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/1d7f0d087b36d07ce34edca5ab119fdaabf7aed7/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L434C20-L434C20).
2. Put the typing information under [`if typing.TYPE_CHECKING`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime_troubles.html#typing-type-checking) along with [`from __future__ import annotations`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime_troubles.html#future-annotations-import-pep-563), which (IMO) is the cleanest way to handle forward references and circular imports in general.
3. Use string literals to declare types, either directly or using [explicit type aliases](https://peps.python.org/pep-0613/#forward-references):

   ```py
   import typing as t

   T = t.TypeVar("T")

   class GenericParent(Generic[T]):
       pass

   class Derived(GenericParent["Derived"]):
       pass
   ```

   Some helpers from `typing` can help perform introspecting this. On Python 3.10:

   ```
   >>> import typing as t
   >>> t._eval_type(Derived.__orig_bases__[0], globals(), {})
   __main__.GenericParent[__main__.Derived]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For only type-safety, most of the time, you can use the [Self](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/) type variable:

Before Python 3.11:

```
from typing import TypeVar

TShape = TypeVar("TShape", bound="Shape")

class Shape:
    def scale(self: TShape, factor: float) -> TShape:
        ...

class Circle(Shape):
    pass

reveal_type(Circle().scale(factor=2))  # Reveals "Circle"
```

From Python 3.11 onwards:

```
from typing import Self

class Shape:
    def scale(self, factor: float) -> Self:
        ...

class Circle(Shape):
    pass

reveal_type(Circle().scale(factor=2))  # Reveals "Circle"
```

Also, you can call the `Derived` class methods by simply calling `self.dervied_method()`.